# Toast in a webpage triggered from server-side

Tags: facebook, popup, html

Consider Facebook, when someone likes your photo you get a mini popup notification in the bottom left corner of the screen which stays for a couple of seconds.
I want to know how is it triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want server-side push to browser, you should use techniques like Comet.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)

There's many implementations with various languages.